# Impala set mem_limit in JDBC for each query before executing

Tags: java, spring-boot, impala, jdbctemplate

I am trying to query from tables, the default mem_limit works for most queries but for few queries it doesn't work , is it possible to set the mem_limit before each query and then execute the query using jdbc

Comment: add `mem_limit` option with desired value in your jdbc url, `jdbc:impala://.......;mem_limit=1gb;`

Comment: That works for all the queries, but I would like to do specific for each query

Comment: i think then you can not use same script. May be while calling the jdbc script, you need to put a condition saying, if table is = mytable then use mem_limit=10gb; else use mem_limit=1gb; end... something like this

Comment: Thanks I had proceeded as you mentioned it is working